# In-memory File for unittesting

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, d

I'd like to write a unit-test for a method that prints to the standard output.
I have already changed the code so it prints to a passed-in `File` instance instead that is `stdout` by default. The only thing I am missing is some in-memory `File` instance that I could pass-in. Is there such a thing? Any recommendation? I wish something like this worked:

```
import std.stdio;

void greet(File f = stdout) {
    f.writeln("hello!");
}

unittest {
    greet(inmemory);
    assert(inmemory.content == "hello!\n")
}

void main() {
    greet();
}
```

Any other approach for unit-testing code that prints to `stdout`?

Comment: Does this need to be cross-platform?

Comment: No; E.g. new line on various platforms might be different. I don't want to test this aspect, but only the printable content. So instead of `File` I'd need something like `OutputStreamWriter` in Java, that is, I'd stay in the level of unicode characters rather than encoding, filesystem, etc. It would be nice if my test run on all platforms of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on `File` which is quite a low level type, pass the object in via an interface.

As you have aluded to in your comment `OutputStreamWriter` in Java is a wrapper of many interfaces designed to be an abstraction over byte streams, etc. I'd do the same:

```
interface OutputWriter {
    public void writeln(string line);
    public string @property content();
    // etc.
}

class YourFile : OutputWriter {
    // handle a File.
}

void greet(ref OutputWriter output) {
    output.writeln("hello!");
}

unittest {

    class FakeFile : OutputWriter {
        // mock the file using an array.
    }

    auto mock = new FakeFile();

    greet(inmemory);
    assert(inmemory.content == "hello!\n")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish similar facility was provided by the standard library. Or some mocking facility to avoid the boilerplate altogether in the 'production' code. This way writeln with all it's whistle and bells is not suitable for production code.

Comment: There are many unit testing libraries available here: http://code.dlang.org/ The one i wrote contains mocking functionality. https://github.com/nomad-software/dunit

Comment: Thanks! I've started looking... of course would prefer something without external dependencies.. For now I just skip the unittesting of this part. :)